# What does it mean by express this puzzle as a CSP

Tags: prolog, clpfd

What is meant by the below for the attached image.

```
By labelling each cell with a variable, express the puzzle as a CSP. Hint:
recall that a CSP is composed of three parts.
```

I initially thought just add variables to each cell like A, B, C  etc to each cell and then constrain those cells, but I do not believe that is correct. I do not want the answer just an explanation of what is required. in terms of CSP.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, a CSP is best divided into *two* parts:

1. State the constraints. This is called the *modeling* part or **model**.
2. **Search** for solutions using *enumeration predicates* like `labeling/2`.

These parts are best kept separate by using a predicate which we call **core relation** and which has the following properties:

- It *posts* the constraints, i.e., it expresses part (1) above.
- Its last argument is the list of variables that still need to be labeled.
- By convention, its name ends with an *underscore* `_`.

Having this distinction in place allows you to:

- try different search strategies without the need to recompile your code
- reason about termination properties of the core relation in isolation of any concrete (and often very costly) search.

I can see how some instructors may decompose part (1) into:

1a. stating the *domains* of the variables, using for example `in/2` constraints
1b. stating the other constraints that hold among the variables.

In my view, this distinction is **artificial**, because `in/2` constraints are constraints like all other constraints in the modeling part, but some instructors may teach this separately also for historical reasons, dating back to the time when CSP systems were not as dynamic as they are now.

Nowadays, you can typically post additional domain restrictions any time you like and freely mix `in/2` constraints with other constraints in any order.

So, the parts that are expected from you are likely: (a) state `in/2` constraints, (b) state further constraints and (c) use enumeration predicates to search for concrete solutions. It also appears that you already have the right idea about how to solve this concrete CSP with this method.

Comment: There is a difference between the modeling/labeling dichotomy and the structure imposed by a core relation: For core relations are constructed such that non-termination is always caused by the core. This is not necessarily the case with the more traditional view.

Comment: Yes: A core relation is a special case of model, satisfying the 3 properties above. What do you think?

Comment: @false. So the conceptual separation of "core relation" and "search" stresses that termination only concerns the core relation, right?

Comment: The actual predicate is **always** of the form `p(X1, ...Xn) :- p_(X1, ...Xn, Zs), labeling(Opts, Zs).`.  So the search part is only the labeling. The "search" part in constraint programming not only permits user-defined search procedures, but also often (accidentally or not) restricts the set of solutions.

Comment: From this it seems that we would also really benefit from a name for this "actual" predicate! *Hull relation*?